# Add hidden div (including it's content) into the DOM

Tags: jquery

I have a hidden div that I want to add (append) into another position in the DOM. The code have I have is not working as expected;

```
$('[class*="time-span"]').on('click', function() {

    var modelPanel = $('.model-detail-panel');

    modelPanel.contents().wrap('<div class="model-detail-panel" id="model-detail">').insertAfter('.timeline');
    modelPanel.slideToggle('fast', function() {
        $('html,body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

The content of the div 'model-detail-panel' is being inserted into the right location, but the actual surrounding div is not getting inserted. Why would this be and are the methods I've used the most appropriate ones to achieve this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Why are using `contents` method? why `wrap`?

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `.model-detail-panel` in a `div` with the same class? And, incidentally, the `wrap()` method returns the object(s) that were wrapped, *not* the element with which they were wrapped; therefore subsequent to the `wrap()` call you're *still* working on/with the `contents()` elements/nodes.

Comment: I'm wanting to take the entire div and insert it elsewhere in the DOM. Would clone be better in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `wrap()` method returns the elements that were wrapped, not the newly-created wrapping-element. Therefore you should use `parent()`:

```
modelPanel.contents().wrap('<div class="model-detail-panel" id="model-detail">').parent().insertAfter('.timeline');
```

References:

- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).
- [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Answer (score 0):

To remain consistant with other chaining methods, [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) returns the jQuery object it was called on, not the wrapper element.

You can apply [parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to the result in order to include the wrapper element in the `insertAfter()` operation:

```
modelPanel.contents().wrap(
    '<div class="model-detail-panel" id="model-detail">'
).parent().insertAfter('.timeline');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var wrapped = $('<div class="model-detail-panel" id="model-detail/">').insertAfter('.timeline')
wrapped.append(model.contents)
```

Comment: Argghhh.. David Thomas's solution is cleaner than mine.. use his